# Part number for intake warm air flap on VW Jetta MkII

Tags: vw, jetta

The vacuum membrane of this device in my car is broken, so it does not work and also it leaks vacuum. The problem is that I do not know the proper name for it and also the part number is not written. I have attached a picture, maybe somebody could tell me the part number (for some reason part numbers for car parts are very difficult to find if it is not possible to read it on the part itself)?

The car is 1984 VW Jetta MkII, engine code EZ.

[image: airbox vacuum unit]

Comment: use this google search https://www.google.com/search?q=1984+VW+Jetta+MkII%2C+engine+code+EZ&oq=1984+VW+Jetta+MkII%2C+engine+code+EZ&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=122&ie=UTF-8#q=1984+VW+Jetta+MkII+EZ+oem+parts     You'll get a ton of parts catalogs to search for your component.

Comment: Vacuum actuator maybe?

Comment: Have you tried contacting a dealership to ask about part number and pricing? Even if you don't purchase it from them, they're using willing to supply the part name and number (along with the price...)

Comment: Have you had any luck getting the part number.  Internet resources for car part numbers are poor.  I shared a link above, did you try it?  Have you contacted the dealer?

Comment: @DucatiKiller, hi, yes, I think I managed to get the part number and order the part on ebay, hopefully it will fit. I asked here because I hoped somebody else has a similar car or access to a parts catalog and could tell me the number. Nobody did, but you can't blame me for trying :)

Comment: Definitely not.  If you found a good online catalogue please share it as an answer with the part number!   Glad your problem is solved  cheers.